# Is client id or server id needed in android code for gcm notification?

Tags: android

I want to know "if client id or server id is needed in android code for gcm notification?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need server id(i.e API Key). you get this server id from google developer console by creating project. Follow these steps to [create project on google developer console](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-04?hl=en)

and you also need client id to send notifications to the clients who subscribed to Push notifications